UV faces are not in the correct order in the UV editor
I have a problem with UV unwrapping.
The order of the faces is correct when I use the Unwrap method but wrong when using the Smart UV Project method. I'm using v4.2.3 LTS.
Here is a screenshot where you can see that the select face is not at the edge in the UV editor. I expect it to be at the edge because it's close to the seam.

Here is my file:
https://drive.google.com/file/d/11vFQOAZScRniX9LTIUDjPPYja-xIcOYs/view?usp=sharing
Thanks!

Smart UV Project will ignore seams and project UVs from multiple directions, then pack the resulting islands. Unwrap will unwrap according to the UV seams. This is expected and is working as intended. Not sure where you got a different expectation from...
What you get with Smart UV Project might be randomly distributed islands. Smart UV Project may be used for baking, painting, light maps or other similar stuff where the position of islands don't matter and if you want a more deliberate arrangement of your UVs you should unwrap and edit the UV map as you see fit.
In other words: for your situation you should use Unwrap and not Smart UV Project.

Thanks for answering! I wasn't aware that seams are ignored when using Smart UV Project. I learned again something new ;-). I will go with the Unwrap operator...
